# Unable to retrieve complete data via API with gridview lazy loading

Tags: flutter

I have 21 items to be returned from API but the code below in flutter on loads up to 20 items and it is not loading more data once it reaches bottom. Hence, it is not showing the complete data.

```
void addItemIntoLisT(var pageCount) async {
    pageCount = pageCount * 10;
    List<Product> products =
        await productService.fetchProducts(pageCount, 10, searchQuery);
    for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
      dataList.add(products[i]);
    }
    debugPrint("dataList length:::${dataList.length}");
    setState(() {
      dataList;
      isLoading = false;
    });
  }
```

Scrolllistener:

```
void scrollListener() {
    if (_scrollController.offset >=
            _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent &&
        !_scrollController.position.outOfRange) {
      setState(() {
        debugPrint("comes to bottom");
        isLoading = true;

        if (isLoading) {
          debugPrint("RUNNING LOAD MORE");
          pageCount = pageCount + 1;
          addItemIntoLisT(pageCount);
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

Init state:

```
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    addItemIntoLisT(0);
    _scrollController.addListener(scrollListener);
  }
```

Widget build:

```
body: SafeArea(
        child: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                horizontal: 8.0,
              ),
              child: SearchBar(
                searchController: searchController,
                hintText: "Try 'Andrew Oppa'",
                searchFunction: (value) {
                  // loadProducts(value);
                },
                onClearFunction: () {
                  searchController.text = "";
                  // loadProducts(searchController.text);
                },
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            GridView.count(
              controller: _scrollController,
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              crossAxisCount: 2,
              mainAxisSpacing: 10.0,
              physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              childAspectRatio: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width /
                  (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 1.5),
              children: dataList.map((product) {
                return Container(
                  // alignment: Alignment.center,
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.2,
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        height: 180,
                        width: 180,
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          image: DecorationImage(
                            image: NetworkImage(
                              product.productGallery![0],
                            ),
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          ),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 10,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        product.productName!,
                        style: const TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 18.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 5,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        product.shortDescription!,
                        maxLines: 1,
                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                        style: const TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 15.0,
                          color: Colors.white60,
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 10,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "$ ${product.discountedPrice.toString()!}",
                        style: const TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 18.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              }).toList(),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

The code above fails to load the 21st item upon scrolling to the most bottom. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: I took a sneak peek and I wonder how it is even scrollable, when you are disabling the scrolling?  physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),? 
I guess you make the whole screen scrollable with SinglleChildScrollView? Well, If you make the whole screen scrollable but not the gridview, the gridview will only show as many Items as it fits there :)